# Play 2.0: Push a URL parameter to the view

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm just learning how the Play 2.0 framework. So I have a quite basic question: I just want to take a URL parameter and display it in the view. How do you do that?

I created the URL pattern:

`GET        /test/:id               controllers.Application.testOutput(id: Long)`

And an apporoptiate methode in `Application`:

```
public static Result testOutput(long id) {
        return ok(
                views.html.test.render(id)
        );
}
```

How do I call the id variable form the view? I know how to call methodes defined in the model in the view, but I don't know how to display the id variable in the view. Is it the right way to pass the id variable to the render methode?

I'd like to understand the underlying concept, so an detailed explanation to the answer would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our test URL will be `http://localhost:9000/greeter?message=hello` and this will output a `text/plain` response with the content of the parameter `message` (ie hello). First, let's define the route

```
GET     /greeter           controllers.Greeter.say(message: String)
```

Then, create a `Greeter` controller (I use Java)

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

// This lets you call the template without the views.html prefix
// import views.html.*;
import views.txt.*;

public class Greeter extends Controller {

  public static Result say(String message) {
    return ok(greeter.render(message));
  }

}
```

You can see that `ok()` calls a scala function defined in the file `app/views/greeter.scala.txt` Here is the content of that file (the first line defines the message parameter of type String used inside the function

```
@(message: String)
I'm the content. Note that you can place
anything you want here. Scala expressions
begin with the '@@' character. For example
next line contains the content of message:
@message
```

In this case I used .txt for file extensions because I wanted plain text response. If you want to produce HTML output, simply make a .scala.html file

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Rally helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The client request is handled by [the Play router](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/routes), which in turn forwards it to some **action** (which is a method inside a Controller)

```
GET    /greeter             Greeter.say
```

From the Play doc

> The last part of a route definition is the Java call. This part is
>   defined by the fully-qualified name of an action method. The action
>   method must be a public static void method of a Controller class. A
>   Controller class must be defined in the controllers package and must
>   be a subclass of play.mvc.Controller.
>
> You can add a Java package before the Controller class name if it
>   isn’t defined directly under the controllers package. The controllers
>   package itself is implicit, so you don’t need to specify it

[Inside the action](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers), you can get the parameters via the `param` object or directly by the method signature:

```
public static void say(String what) {
    ... 
}
```

and you can pass objects to the template via [`render(what)`](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/mvc/Controller.html#render%28java.lang.Object...%29) like you do in your sample.

Finally [your template](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates) can access those object with the `${what}` syntax.

**EDIT** *This is the Play 1.x way of doing things. I didn't notice your tag, but still hope this helps. Play2 uses the new Scala template engine, [here is the guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates). It seems you must declare your parameters at the beginning of the template, then you can access them via the `@what` syntax. That's because the template is now a compiled Scala function, so it can do type checking at compile time and things like this. You pass parameters to this function with `render(what)` (like you do) . I personally don't use Play2.0 myself: it's a big improvement from the technical point of view, at the cost of being less intuitive and more verbose. I don't think that simpler projects benefit from these improvements*

Comment: After I passed the parameter to the `render` function, how can I call the variable in the view? Do you know the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2 templates are just plain functions, so you can call them as you would call any function.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail on how one would write a function in the modele to display a variable from the URL. Can I only call functions I defined in the model from the view?